# There needs more education for pedestrians dealing with cyclists

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence right? "There needs more education for pedestrians dealing with cyclists." Where is it used (by native speakers)? What's it subject?

Source: http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-41036581

Comment: I believe the sentence should say **"needs to be".**

Comment: The subject is "education."
There needs to be education --> Education (subj) needs to be (verb) there (adv).

Comment: Why would "there" need education?

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect.

"There" looks like the subject but it is really not. It is what is called a 'dummy subject'. As per [curious-proofreader](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/8303/curious-proofreader)'s comment:

> The subject is "education."
>
> There needs to be education --> Education (*subj*) needs to be (*verb*) there (*adv*).

---

A guess as to why the article has this error: it is possible that originally the sentence had a subject. For example, the person quoted could have literally said:

> People just step out in front and expect us to stop. *The public* needs more education for pedestrians dealing with cyclists.

The author of the article may have thought that having "people" at the start of one sentence and "the public" at the start of the next is too much repetition, and tried to rewrite the second sentence without properly checking it.

Somewhat opposing this argument is the fact that the sentence is a direct quote of what the driver said, and in the preceding paragraph a modification of the quote was indicated with [square brackets], so another explanation is that the author forgot the words - I am sure it has happened to you as well that you were "thinking faster than you were typing" - still a proofread of the article should have caught this.

Answer (score 0):

*There needs more education for pedestrians dealing with cyclists*.
The subject here is **There** as a singular. Actually, we can use **there** as a subject or noun in front position.
Check out this: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there